# The Welch years at G.E. combined strategic insights with managerial innovations

Tags: meaning-in-context

> **The Welch years at G.E. combined strategic insights with managerial innovations.** Mr. Welch early on recognized the rise of Asia, then led by Japan, as a manufacturing powerhouse, and he shed G.E. businesses that he deemed vulnerable, moving into new ones.

Why put the years as a subject? It is Mr Welch combined strategic insights with managerial innovations.

Comment: Not necessarily. Welch himself may have been a major influence during the period *named* after him (which I'm sure only means the period starting from when he became CEO in 1981, not 1960 when he first joined the company). But your cited writer might well have specifically *intended* the implication that ***others were also involved in the process that happened during that period***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica,ok, then would it be more sensible having the welch years function as adverbial instead of subject?

Comment: Feasibly it might be "more sensible" to use Welch himself as the subject (rather than his eponymously-named "period of high office") if you insist on saying Welch is the ***only*** "agent of change". But even then I don't think that would be a particularly strong argument. Some people might say the "personification" of that period (into a "conscious agent" capable of planning / instigating organisational changes) is entirely a stylistic device, and that my fine distinction is effectively illusory. But I still think it's a perfectly good stylistic choice regardless of any semantic implications.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, thank you. I was having trouble in understanding this kind of sentence structure. Now I know it is "sentence with non-life subject" in grammar. And for time as subject, it should be translated as an adverbial.

Comment: Now I can better understand exactly *why* you had a problem with this construction, I think I should retract my closevote (for Primarily Opinion-Based, because it's just a stylistic choice), and post an actual "Answer". Note that I'm not really interested in labels such as "subject, adverbial". Native Anglophones can learn English perfectly well without having a clue what such labels actually mean, and it's positively *unhelpful* if the label "subject" leads you to assume it must refer to a **person** (or at least something "alive"). Language ***is*** metaphor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The highlighted "verb subject" in...

> ***The Welch years at G.E.*** combined strategic insights with managerial innovations

...can be seen as a literary / stylistic device that effectively "personifies" the period during which Welch was the CEO of G.E. (so it can serve as the subject of the verb ***to combine***).

It's perfectly possible the writer fully intended that highlighted noun phrase to *exactly and only* stand in for Welch himself (***he*** was the one actually doing all that clever combining). But it's equally possible he meant *the company as a whole* engaged in that process, so there's at least a *potential* difference in nuance of meaning. In practice though, the choice was probably made on stylistic (not *semantic*) grounds.

---

For a very common context where a period of time can be "personified" in this way, consider...

> *The 20th century **saw** a dramatic increase in global population*

...where obviously no-one thinks in terms of "the 20th century" being in any sense a living thing (with a mind and sensory organs?) capable of *literally* "seeing" anything at all.